# Change url based on dynamic field

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

Is there a way to change the url once the user logs into the system? For example, if my login url is `demo.xxx.com/login`, after user is authenticated I want it to change to `abc.xxx.com/dashboard`. abc is the user group and is determined when user is authenticated. My application is based on spring boot and uses spring security for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set the default success url in the a spring security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter bean. If using XML configuration I believe this can also be configured although I'm not sure how off hand.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
            .loginPage( "/login" )
            .defaultSuccessUrl( "/dashboard" );
    }
}
```

If you need even finer control of the redirect, you can implement your own authentication success handler and provide a custom redirect strategy.

```
http.formLogin().successHandler( new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    {
        setRedirectStrategy( new RedirectStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void sendRedirect( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url ) throws IOException {
                // Put your logic here for sending redirects
                response.sendRedirect("https://xyx.mydomain.com/dashboard");
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: I have to set the url after the user is authenticated and when it goes to url dashboard.  Based on user group, the url should be modified. During authentication I donot have these information to check the user group.                                                                                                                        
   @RequestMapping(value = "/portal/asset")
    public String dashboard(Model model) {
  try{   
   model.addAttribute("1", "1");
   return "dashboard";
        } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "error";  
  }
 }